# Disable ES5 transpilation for production builds of Vaadin Flow 14.2 (or 16) apps

Tags: vaadin, ecmascript-5, vaadin-flow

[This blog post](https://vaadin.com/blog/improving-the-developer-experience-for-java-developers) by the Vaadin team has a section, *Skipping ES5 transpilation for faster development-mode frontend builds*. (I assume *ES5* means EcmaScript 5, that is, JavaScript 5.)

That section mentions that while ES5 transpilation is no longer done by default in develop mode, it is still done by default in production mode. To quote:

> Starting from 14.2, the transpilation of JavaScript code to ES5 (required by IE11) is not done by default in development mode, but you can still enable it with configuration, if necessary. For production builds with the build-frontend goal, it is still done by default.

➥ How can I turn off the ES5 transpilation entirely, in both develop mode as well as production mode?

I will deploy only to modern browsers, not Internet Explorer nor the first generation of Microsoft Edge. So no need for ES5 support.

Answer (score 3):

For 14.1 there is no flags as there is for 14.2, but for 14.1 you could add to webpack.config.js

```
/**
 * This file has been autogenerated as it didn't exist or was made for an older incompatible version.
 * This file can be used for manual configuration will not be modified if the flowDefaults constant exists.
 */
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const flowDefaults = require('./webpack.generated.js');

flowDefaults.module.rules.splice(0,1);
flowDefaults.plugins.splice(1,1);

module.exports = merge(flowDefaults, {

});
```

which would remove the Babel transpilation rule and plugin.

This would seem to work also for 14.2.0.beta1, but it might be worth it to make a request to have a flag for disabling transpilation.

Comment: For 14.6 replace `flowDefaults.module.rules.splice(0,1);` with `flowDefaults.module.rules.splice(1,1);` since the Babel rule is no more first in the list of rules in webpack.generated.js.